# Appium iOS Safari Open new tab, accept alerts and switch between two tabs

Tags: ios, safari, tabs, appium, alert

So I'm testing a web app for which I have to open a new tab, switch to it, do some input, than switch back to the first tab and this more than once.
I try to open the new tab this way:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) AppiumTestBase.getDriver()).executeScript("window.open('http://google.com', '_blank')");
```

This causes the following alert to appear:

[image: iOS pop-up]

But I'm not able to accept it through automation with Appium. Things that I have tried:

- Using the following capabilities: "safariAllowPopups" and "autoAcceptAlerts"
- Changing the according settings for safari in the iOS sim
- .switchTo().alert().accept(); I also waited for the Popup.
- Switchting to native context before accepting the popup
- Clicking the pop up by name .findElement(By.name("Allow")).click();

What I have not tried:

- Taping on the screen according to the pop-up coordinates. I didn't try this since I'm not sure on how to get the position of the "Allow" button.

And my other question is how would I switch between two tabs? I haven't tried anything yet, but research would suggest that I try it with window contexts.

Some other information:

- Currently testing with a iPhoneSE iOS 9.3 Simulator, the solution should work for several configurations
- Appium is on the most recent version
- The class "AppiumTestBase"s only purpose is to set capabilities and initialize the AppiumDriver

Answer (score 1):

Please try this cap after i change to this no popup from safari anymore

```
desired_capabilities=automationName:XCUITest,browserName:safari,platformName:iOS,platformVersion:11.1,deviceName:iPhone 6,nativeWebTap:True,safariIngoreFraudWarning:True
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution suggested by Atthaboon Sanurt, but it didn't help.
There was no alert, but the new window/tab didn't open either.

Here where the problem is reported: 
https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6864

So far it looks like there is no solution and plans to fix it.